# What is Chef's "Secret Recipe" in Donut County?

Tags: achievements, donut-county

There's a trophy option for "Make Chef's secret soup recipe." What is the recipe?

[image]

I assume that you can get this trophy on the level where you are at Chef's restaurant.

I've tried the following combinations with no luck:

- The recipe that completes the level (soup + salt + pepper)
- Soup + Salt + Pepper + 1 bug
- Soup + Salt + Pepper + 2 bugs
- Soup + Salt + 1 bug
- Soup + Pepper + 1 bug

I can't figure out any other combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need three shakes of pepper and two shakes of salt. The recipe can be found in Trashopedia after you complete the Cat Soup level.

[image: It's bookmarked. "Secret Soup Recipe: 2 shakes salt, 3 shakes pepper."]